# Superséer (pour traduire le mot anglais "override") a t-il existé ?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire

Il y a des mots qu'on ne voit apparaître qu'une seule fois, comme *affin*

> Je suis un Elfe et un affin ici, dit Legolas, courroucé à son tour
> (Le Seigneur des Anneaux)

Mais il y en a un qui m’embarrasse, c'est une traduction d'un mot anglais utilisé régulièrement dans un contexte informatique : *override*. Quand on substitue un fichier à un autre, par exemple.

Eh bien, il me semble qu'il a existé un mot, fugitivement dans les années 90 pour tenter de le traduire : *superséer*. Mais je n'arrive pas à retrouver la moindre source. Et plus encore : je ne crois pas qu'un verbe séer existe.

Mais c'est étrange, j'en suis convaincu. D'autant qu'il sonne assez bien pour dire que quelque-chose supersée autre-chose, c'est à dire prend le pas sur.

S'il n'existe pas, si c'est une construction temporaire d'un journaliste, ou un égarement de ma mémoire... J'aimerais en avoir le coeur net.

Comment: https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/supers%C3%A9er

Comment: Bonjour ! Perso. je ne me souviens pas de l'avoir entendu, mais on a _supplanter_ et _surclasser_, par exemple, ou _prévaloir sur_, _remplacer_ ou simplement _annuler/neutraliser_. La question m'a fait penser à _to supersede_ et j'étais convaincu que _superséder_ était un verbe ; on l'a déjà eu techniquement, mais c'est _surseoir_ aujourd'hui. Il y a peut-être aussi le reflet du substantif _overseer_. Quelqu'un s'est posé la question [ici](https://francearchives.fr/fr/facomponent/1b86a35ee13cc1b69de7f0a52b23f49507c1e8d4).

Comment: override n'est pas une subsitution. override function/ fonction de neutralisation; fonction d'interruption// ou changement forcé dans certains cas. En anglais, on a supercede et peut-être vous pensez à ça? :) Aussi, neutraliser ou annuler. Tout cela en informatique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

L'anglais *[supersede](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/supersede)* (remplacer, supplanter), parfois écrit de manière controversée *[supercede](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/supercede)*, vient du verbe français « [superséder](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/dictionnaire-godefroy/superseder) » (s'abstenir, renvoyer à plus tard) qui a fini par être supplanté par son doublon « [surseoir](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/surseoir) ». On en trouve encore quelques rares occurrences au XVIII<sup>e</sup> siècle.

> *Les Prétendants de Longueville n'ont point proprement été demandeurs en séparation d'actions; mais ils ont simplement défendu à la cumulation qui en a été demandée de la part de Sa Majesté ; de sorte que c'est à la demande de ce monarque qu'il a été **supersédé** de statuer et non pas à celle de MM. de Villeroy et de Matignon.*
> *Annales historiques du Comté de Neuchâtel et Valangin*, p 316, 1707.

L'étymologie de ces verbes est le latin *super sedere*, littéralement « s'asseoir au dessus ». Il est amusant de constater qu'on retrouve un peu la même métaphore que celle du latin, mais en plus radical, dans l'expression actuelle ***[s'asseoir dessus](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/s%E2%80%99asseoir_dessus)***.

L'anglais *override* s'appuie aussi sur une métaphore similaire (littéralement *chevaucher au dessus*) avec un sens pouvant être celui de *supersede*.

[etymonline: Override](https://www.etymonline.com/word/override)

> Figurative meaning "to set aside arrogantly" is by 1827, from the notion of "to trample down," hence "supersede."

On ne trouve pas trace d'un ***superséer*** dans les années 70 ou autres mais ce néologisme a peut-être été utilisé sporadiquement. J'ai aussi parfois entendu le verbe anglais repris quasiment tel quel en français comme par exemple dans :

> *Cette nouvelle méthode **supersède** l'ancienne.*

Comment: Merci, c'est possible que j'ai entendu supersède, et que ma mémoire m'ait fait perdre le "d" ensuite.

Comment: In British and American English, the word is supersede. supercede is the variant but any good editor would change the c to an s.